# Работодатель требует : понимание многопоточности . Что это может в себя включать?

Tags: java, android

Ну начал я писать программы и  дойдя до многопоточности ничего сложного в этом не увидел. Ну да программа работает в несколько потоков и главное чтобы всё было синхронизировано. Ясное дело это сложно, но механизм достижения в своем принципе прост. Считаю принцип многопоточности похож на: есть кирпич, как их класть друг на друга чтобы не упала стена не сложно , а вот строить дворец можно начать, и можно многого добиться, но могут возникнуть проблемы, если не рассчитать всякие строительные тонкости. 
   Но почему же говорят, что многопоточность сложная тема и понять ее не просто. Что же она в себя включает ? Желательно сузить ответ до многопоточности в андроид приложениях

Comment: *У некоторых людей отсутствует часть мозга, необходимая для написания многопоточного кода.*

Comment: Ну как мне ответить на вопрос: Что вы знаете о многопоточности? Ну какой то кривой вопрос, который заставляет начать говорить о банальных вещах, которые не совсем даже к программированию относятся.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если смотреть на многопоточность в контексте разработки обычных Андроид-приложений, то необходимый минимум это понимание что такое `UI thread`, что такое `non-UI thread`, что можно делать в первом и втором, как их синхронизировать между собой, как вызывать один из другого и как передавать данные между ними.

Если в этом топике есть у вас понимание, то это и будет ответ на вопрос "Что вы знаете о многопоточности?".

[Самые сливки по теме здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z5MZ0jL2BM)